# Change Broswer URL, not actual paths or file locations

Tags: .htaccess, url

I'm running apache2 on Linux and I've not been able to find a solution to this.

I want to change the URL shown in the browser, but not change any real paths etc for files.

Eg:

http://127.0.0.1/school/northern/

http://127.0.0.1/school/southern/

I'd like the URL to appear as the following for both:

http://127.0.0.1/school/

But I don't want to change any paths to relating to northern or southern, they must remain as is.

I've tried adding a .htaccess in the northern folder as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This forces a redirect back to `http://127.0.0.1/school` and the files aren't there so it fails.

Is this possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Let me ask you a simple question. If you type in http://127.0.0.1/school.. what is there to show which one you want? Northern or Southern? The webserver is not a mind reader. You have to give it something to know where to redirect to. You'd have to put an index at /school and have the user choose where they want to go otherwise.

Comment: Hi. In /school there is an index.php that does offer various options, including links to northern & southern.  if i do the rewrite rule it sort of works but relative paths etc are all changed and are relative to the rewritten url not the original. Is it possible to just change what URL the browser shows without changing any paths etc ?

Comment: I think you did not yet fully understand what rewriting actually is. This is _not_ just a cosmetic thing (what is shown inside the browsers URL line). If you remove information from the URL the way you suggest then there is no way for the http server to later _guess_ it again. It does not know what you actually request with the change you suggest. How should it? Not on the level of the http server.

Comment: @arkascha thanks. I wasn't sure if this was possible or not.. now i know not :)